# How do I consolidate eventlisteners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, fetch-api, event-listener

I have an API app that lists of names that clicked on a modal pops up and shows the data.

There is another button that is connected to a second modal with more data.

The problem is that this second modal runs through all the data instead of only displaying the proper data for the name selected. I was told the reason is because I have two event listeners but I should only have 1.

Here is my codepen and here is where I was told the problem was.

https://codepen.io/drxl/pen/WNjJQXa

```js
function addListItem(pokemon) {
  let pokeUl = document.querySelector('.list-group');
  let listItem = document.createElement('li');
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  let baseStatsButton = document.querySelector('#base-stats-button');
  button.innerText = pokemon.name;
  button.classList.add('btn');
  button.classList.add('btn-primary');
  listItem.classList.add('group-list-item');
  button.setAttribute("data-target", "#my-modal");
  button.setAttribute("data-toggle", "modal");
  listItem.appendChild(button);
  pokeUl.appendChild(listItem);
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    showDetails(pokemon);
  });
  baseStatsButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    showStatModal(pokemon);
  });
}
```

Comment: Please look at my amended answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now when you add the pokemon, you add the same click event listener to the stats button every time. That ends up executing the event handler number-of-pokemon times when clicked. There is only one button so only one event listener is needed

What we can do is to set up a global currentPokemon outside the functions. Then when you click a pokemon button, you save the pokemon and when you click base stats, show the base stats for currentPokemon

So let's move some constants out of the add function and save the pokemon clicked

```
const pokeUl = document.querySelector('.list-group');
const baseStatsButton = document.querySelector('#base-stats-button');
let currentPokemon; // define a reusable variable
function addListItem(pokemon) {
  let listItem = document.createElement('li');
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerText = pokemon.name;
  button.classList.add('btn');
  button.classList.add('btn-primary');
  listItem.classList.add('group-list-item');
  button.setAttribute("data-target", "#my-modal");
  button.setAttribute("data-toggle", "modal");
  listItem.appendChild(button);
  pokeUl.appendChild(listItem);
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
     showDetails(pokemon);
     currentPokemon = pokemon; // save
  });
};
```

then use it in the stats

```
   function showStatModal() {
      if (!currentPokemon) return; // for some reason we have invoked the modal before clicking
      const item = currentPokemon;
```

```js
let pokemonRepository = (function () {
   let pokemonList = [];
   let apiUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=150';
   let searchInput = document.querySelector("#searchIn");

   function add(pokemon) {
      pokemonList.push(pokemon);
   }

   function getAll() {
      return pokemonList;
   }

   const pokeUl = document.querySelector('.list-group');
   const baseStatsButton = document.querySelector('#base-stats-button');
   let currentPokemon;
   function addListItem(pokemon) {
      let listItem = document.createElement('li');
      let button = document.createElement('button');
      button.innerText = pokemon.name;
      button.classList.add('btn');
      button.classList.add('btn-primary');
      listItem.classList.add('group-list-item');
      button.setAttribute("data-target", "#my-modal");
      button.setAttribute("data-toggle", "modal");
      listItem.appendChild(button);
      pokeUl.appendChild(listItem);
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
         showDetails(pokemon);
         currentPokemon = pokemon; 
      });
   }

   baseStatsButton.addEventListener('click', showStatModal);

   function loadList() {
      return fetch(apiUrl).then(function (response) {
         return response.json();
      }).then(function (json) {
         json.results.forEach(function (item) {
            let pokemon = {
               name: item.name,
               detailsUrl: item.url
            };
            add(pokemon);
         });
      }).catch(function (e) {
         console.error(e);
      })
   }

   function loadDetails(item) {
      let url = item.detailsUrl;
      return fetch(url).then(function (response) {
         return response.json();
      }).then(function (details) {
         //Add details to item
         item.imageUrl = details.sprites.front_default;
         item.imageUrlBack = details.sprites.back_default;
         item.height = details.height / 10;
         item.weight = details.weight / 10;
         // pokemon types
         item.types = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < details.types.length; i++) {
            item.types.push(details.types[i].type.name);
         }
         item.types = item.types.join(',  ');
         //pokemon abilities
         item.abilities = [];
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-redeclare
         for (var i = 0; i < details.abilities.length; i++) {
            item.abilities.push(details.abilities[i].ability.name);
         }
         item.abilities = item.abilities.join(',  ');

      }).catch(function (e) {
         console.error(e);
      });
   }

   //loads the stats for 2nd modal

   function loadStats(item) {
      let url = item.detailsUrl;
      return fetch(url).then(function (response) {
         return response.json();
      }).then(function (details) {
         //add details to stats
         item.stats = details.stats.map(({ base_stat, stat: { name } }) =>
            `${name}: ${base_stat}`).join("<br/>")


      }).catch(function (e) {
         console.error(e);
      });
   }


   function showDetails(item) {
      pokemonRepository.loadDetails(item).then(function () {
         // console.log("item:", item);
         showModal(item);
      });
   }

   function showModal(item) {
      pokemonRepository.loadDetails(item).then(function () {
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         let modalBody = $(".modal-body");
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         let modalTitle = $(".modal-title");

         //clears previous content in modal
         modalTitle.empty();
         modalBody.empty();

         //create elenebtb for pokemon name
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         let nameElement = $("<h1>" + item.name + "</h1>");

         //create img element
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         let imageElementFront = $('<img class="modal-img" style="width:50%">');
         imageElementFront.attr("src", item.imageUrl);
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         let imageElementBack = $('<img class="modal-img" style="width:50%">');
         imageElementBack.attr("src", item.imageUrlBack);

         //create element for pokemon height 
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         let heightElement = $("<p>" + "Height: " + item.height + "m</p>");

         //for pokemon weight
         let weightElement = $("<p>" + "Weight: " + item.weight + "kgs</p>");
         //pokemon types
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         let typesElement = $("<p>" + "Types: " + item.types + "</p>");

         //pokemon abilities 
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         let typesAbilities = $("<p>" + "Abilities: " + item.abilities + "</p>");


         //eventlistener to for search  bar
         searchInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
            let listPokemon = document.querySelectorAll('.group-list-item');
            let value = searchInput.value.toUpperCase();

            listPokemon.forEach(function (pokemon) {
               if (pokemon.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                  pokemon.style.display = '';
               } else {
                  pokemon.style.display = 'none'
               }
            })
         });

         modalTitle.append(nameElement);
         modalBody.append(imageElementFront);
         modalBody.append(imageElementBack);
         modalBody.append(heightElement);
         modalBody.append(weightElement);
         modalBody.append(typesElement);
         modalBody.append(typesAbilities);


         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         $('#my-modal').modal('toggle');
      });
   }



   function loadStatDetails(item) {
      pokemonRepository.loadStats(item).then(function () {
         showStatModal(item);
      });
   }
   function showStatModal() {
      if (!currentPokemon) return; // for some reason we have invoked the modal before clicking
      const item = currentPokemon;
      pokemonRepository.loadStats(item).then(function () {
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         let StatmodalBody = $(".Statmodal-body");
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         let StatmodalTitle = $(".Statmodal-title");

         //clears previous content in modal
         StatmodalTitle.empty();
         StatmodalBody.empty();

         //create elenebtb for pokemon name
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
         let nameElement = $("<h1>" + item.name + "</h1>");

         //add stats
         let statsElement = $("<p>" + item.stats + "<p>");

         StatmodalTitle.append(nameElement);
         StatmodalBody.append(statsElement);

         $('#my-Statmodal').modal('show');

      });
   }


   return {
      add: add,
      getAll: getAll,
      addListItem: addListItem,
      loadList: loadList,
      loadDetails: loadDetails,
      showDetails: showDetails,
      loadStats: loadStats,
      loadStatDetails: loadStatDetails,
   };

})();

pokemonRepository.loadList().then(function () {

   pokemonRepository.getAll().forEach(function (pokemon) {
      pokemonRepository.addListItem(pokemon);
   });
});

let link = document.getElementById("back-to-top");
var amountScrolled = 250;

//makes button show
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
   if (this.window.pageYOffset > amountScrolled) {
      link.classList.add('show');
   } else {
      link.className = 'back-to-top';
   }
});

//scrolls to top
link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var distance = 0 - window.pageYOffset;
   var increments = distance / (500 / 16);
   function animateScroll() {
      window.scrollBy(0, increments);
      if (window.pageYOffset <= document.body.offsetTop) {
         clearInterval(runAnimation);
      }
   };
   // Loop the animation function
   var runAnimation = setInterval(animateScroll, 16);
});
```

```css
/*
* Prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io
* PostCSS: v7.0.29,
* Autoprefixer: v9.7.6
* Browsers: last 4 version
*/

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(3, 136, 180);
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #ffcb05!important;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: #3d7dca!important;
}

.navbar-logo {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #ffcb05!important;
  border: #3d7dca solid 6px!important;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal-close {
  background-color: #ee1515;
  border: white solid 2px;
  color: white;
  padding: 8.5px 16.5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.modal-close:active {
  border-color: #ee1515;
  background-color: white;
  color: #ee1515;
}

.modal-title h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #3d7dca;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.modal p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #3d7dca;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.list-group {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  margin: 2rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.list-group li {
  width: auto;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.Statmodal-body p {
  margin-left: 3%;
}

.btn {
  /*  background-color:   #cc1313;*/
  background-color: #db0606;
  border: black solid 2px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 24px 72px;
  width: 300px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border: black solid 2px;
  color: #ee1515;
}

.btn-outline-success:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #ee1515;
  border: black 2px solid;
}

.btn-primary {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #ee1515;
  background-color: white;
}

#search-button {
  background-color: #db0606;
  border: black solid 2px;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 25px;
}

.modal-footer {
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: none;
}

.modal-button {
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}

.back-to-top {
  background-color: #ee1515;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

a.back-to-top {
  font-weight: 1000;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.back-to-top:hover,
.back-to-top:focus,
.back-to-top:visited {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.back-to-top.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 727px) {
  .btn {
    width: 250px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:627px) {
  .btn {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:575px) {
  .justify-content-between {
    -webkit-box-pack: center!important;
    -ms-flex-pack: center!important;
    justify-content: center!important;
  }
  .form-inline {
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #search-button {
    margin-top: .5rem;
    padding: 4px 42px;
  }
  .modal p {
    font-size: 1.5rem!important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
  .modal p {
    font-size: 1.5rem!important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 493px) {
  .justify-content-between {
    -webkit-box-pack: center!important;
    -ms-flex-pack: center!important;
    justify-content: center!important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:450px) {
  .modal-header {
    -webkit-box-align: center!important;
    -ms-flex-align: center!important;
    align-items: center!important;
  }
  .modal-title h1 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }
  button {
    font-size: .85rem;
  }
  .modal p {
    font-size: 1rem!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>PokemonAPI</title>
  <link href="img/Poke_Ball.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!--Nav-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
    <a class="navbar-brand">PokemonAPI<img class="navbar-logo" src="img/Poke_Ball.png"></a>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input id="searchIn" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search for a Pokemon" aria-label="Search for Pokemon">
      <button id="search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </nav>

  <!--list of pokemon-->
  <ul class="list-group"></ul>



  <div class="modal fade" id="my-modal" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="pokemonModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" aria-labelledby="pokemonModalLabel">Modal 1 title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="modal-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="base-stats-button" class="btn modal-button" data-bs-target="#my-Statmodal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Base Stats</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="my-Statmodal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="pokemonStatModalLabel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="Statmodal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel2" aria-labelledby="pokemonStatModalLabel">Modal 2 title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="modal-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="Statmodal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn modal-button" data-bs-target="#my-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Back to Pokemon</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>












  <!--Top of Page Button-->
  <a href="#" id="back-to-top" class="back-to-top" style="display: inline;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up fa-2x"></i></a>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--PolyFills-->
  <script src="js/promise-polyfill.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fetch-polyfill.js"></script>

  <!--JS-->
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I would guess, that while the answer gives a solution, it does not explain what the problem with the `baseStatsButton.addEventListener('click',` in the original code is. I know there is `Also no need to add event handler to the stats button all the time` and I know why this is a problem. But for the OP - or anyone else facing that problem - this probably won't explain it.

Comment: It doesn't work, the whole app is broken.  There are now no clickable buttons showing

Comment: If you take  the event listener our for the list item function it will break the 2nd modal from showing data

Comment: I don't have the experience for that, I am doing a bootcamp (gives you an idea of my skill level) and am just trying to add on to my project.  Glad you know the answer.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed the code. It was simpler than I expected.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate  it!  Why do we need the PokeUI const?  When I comment it out nothing happens, same for baseStatsButton in the addListItem function.  So essentially we are trying to save the pokemon that was selected, and then tell the app to show details in the showStatModal when we click on the stat button?    Also what does "let currentPokemon;" mean?   Is that a shorthand I have never seen that, i thought you have to set it = to something?

Comment: Ah, *I* forgot to delete them from the function!!! See the code. `let currentPokemon;` is to define it outside the functions to be overwritten later.

Comment: Ok i left the poke ui inside and it still works, const baseStatsButton has to be left outside though.  I'll just keep the two const.  What I meant was I thought when you use "let" you have to set it equal to something, why is there no equal sign with it?

Comment: You can define a var (with var or let) and not initialise it. Since I do not know what the currentPokemon is at definition time, I leave it uninitialised

Comment: Please do move the pokeUI outside too since you do not want to get it EVERY time